# When calling a function from "GameManager" script, the following error appears "NullReferenceException"

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm making an course on udemy. The lesson explain how to trigger a function that stops the world movement when the player hits a hazard. I copied it exactly as the class shows.

This is the "PlayerController" script which has the trigger to call the function that stops the world movement.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour

{
    public GameManager theGM;
    
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
    
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
    
    }

    
    public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
        if (other.tag == "Hazards") {
            Debug.Log("Hit Hazard");
            theGM.HitHazard();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the "GameManager" script which contains the function that stops the world movement.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool canMove;
    static public bool _canMove;
    public float worldSpeed;
    static public float _worldSpeed;    
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        _canMove = canMove;
        _worldSpeed = worldSpeed;   
    }

    public void HitHazard() {
        _canMove = false;
        canMove = false;
    }
}
```

When the player collides with a hazard its runs the "OnTriggerEnter" function, it shows on the console that the player hit a hazard, but when it tries to call the "HitHazard" function the following error appears: "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

Already tried to rewrite both codes and search in the internet, but still could not solve it.

Comment: NullRefernceException appear when you forgot to set your field in the inspector. You should probably check that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A NullReferenceException is when you try to access something (field/property/method) on a null instance.

```
object obj = null;
obj.Something(); // <<< NullReferenceException is throwed
```

In unity you can get more informations there (File name & line number):
[image: 1]

Edit:
In your code the only thing that can be null is your GameManager reference "theGM" in your PlayerController. Try to bind it correctly in the editor, or use the Singleton pattern.

I hope i helped you

Answer (score 0):

`NullReferenceException` means that a field you are trying to access is null, Unity logs lines where does it happen, usually appearing logged as `FunctionPath (at file: xx)`

xx - Line where it occured.

file = Path to the file in your Assets folder.

You can fix it in many ways, here are two.

1. Make `Awake` function with code that adds the `GameManager` `Component` to active GameObject:

```
void Awake()
{
   theGM = base.AddComponent<GameManager>();
}
```

2. Add the `GameManager` `Component` to `GameObject` in Unity and assign it to the field `theGM`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys. The problem was that I didn't set the GameManager in the inspector. I tried adding it to the object field in te inspector but still the error continued, I think because I changed something in the code while trying to fix it. So I rewrited te code again and added the GameManager object to the Inspector, now it works.

```
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour

{
    public GameManager theGM;
    
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }

    
    public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
        if (other.tag == "Hazards") {
            Debug.Log("Hit Hazard");
            theGM.HitHazard();
        }
    }
}
```